# ¿Cómo puedo capturar con javascript el cierre de mi navegador?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un problema, necesito capturar el cierre de mi navegador con JavaScript para poder cerrar la sesión actual del usuario y así validar que solo se tenga una sesión abierta del usuario.

Lo que he intentado hasta ahora es capturar el cierre del navegador con `onload` y `onbeforeunload` de la siguiente forma:

```
<body onload=verificarSesion() onbeforeunload=salirSesion() class="fixed-navbar">
```

Y el JavaScript es el siguiente:

```
function verificarSesion() {
    console.log("sesion activa"); 
}

function salirSesion() {

    setTimeout(() => {
        var idusuario = $("#txt_idusuario_general").val(); 
    }, 100);

    $.ajax({
            url: "../controlador/usuario/controlador_cerrar_sesion.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              id: idusuario
            }
          }).done(function (resp) {
            var data = JSON.parse(resp);          
          })

}
```

Comment: Sin ofender pero esto que tiene que ver con ***MySQL***?

Comment: Se me ocurre: si no tienes actividad por n minutos, cerrar la sesión. Si quiere conectarse desde otro lado y la sesión está abierta avisarle que se le va a cerrar en el resto de los dispositivos. Intentar detectar el cierre del browser, no suena confiable y para darte un ejemplo, yo jamás cierro el navegador (por lo que no es indicio de sí estoy usando o no alguna app). Y qué pasaría si tiene dos ventanas abiertas en el mismo navegador? Se caen las dos por cerrar una?

Comment: @JavierG.Raya No me percaté, ya está arreglado.

Comment: @FrancoBerardi Lo de la validación del timeout se puede realizar a nivel de fronted con el propio JavaScript? o trabajo directamente con los archivos backend? en mi caso usando PHP?

Comment: Que me corrijan, yo me imagino que este req corresponde al back y no al front. Tengo 0 PHP, pero toda app del lado de back soporta setear un timeout a la sesión. Con seguridad te digo que php también

Comment: @Isanchezo de nada amigo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, es que ahí el beforeunload que necesitas agarrar es el de la ventana. Ya que tienes JQuery, puedes probar un listener como

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    salirsesion();
})
```

Edito: La [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) dice que es compatible con todos los navegadores.

**He visto comparaciones y pruebas en las que ven que el navegador corre tu lógica del beforeunload por un tiempo finito antes de cerrar la ventana/pestaña y borrar la memoria asociada. Procura que sea lo más concreto posible.** Haz pruebas corriendo cosas más sencillas dentro del listener (dentro del método) para confirmar que el evento es escuchado (en vez de todo el ajax, corre un `console.log`, haz pruebas!) o si pasa que tu ejecución se interrumpe en los diferentes navegadores.

Ya después, estaría bien que analices otros escenarios como el timeout de la sesión inactiva, etc.

Comment: Hola, intenté con tú script y me funciona solo con el navegador Chrome y en modo normal (no incógnito) y cuando se cierra la pestaña, no detecta cuando cierra el navegador; he probado con Edge y Firefox y en estos no me detecta el script en ningún modo (normal ni incógnito).

Comment: Edité la respuesta, @lsanchezo